# xsl hashmap keys not accessible with name()

Tags: xml, xslt, hash, xslt-1.0

I often use tricky hashmaps in xsl but this time... I have no idea on how can I solve this issue...

Relevent extract of XML :

```
<DOCUMENT>
  <PANO_LIV_MIN>True</PANO_LIV_MIN>
  <PANO_LIV_INTER>True</PANO_LIV_INTER>
  <!-- PANO_LIV_MATIN voluntarily ommited --> 
</DOCUMENT>
```

Relevent extract of XSL :

```
  [...]
  <xsl:variable name="hashmap">
    <entry key="PANO_LIV_MATIN">Matin</entry>
    <entry key="PANO_LIV_MIN">Ministre</entry>
    <entry key="PANO_LIV_INTER">International</entry>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="PANO_LIV_MATIN[text() = 'True'] | PANO_LIV_MIN[text() = 'True'] | PANO_LIV_INTER[text() = 'True']">

    <span class="panorama">
      <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($hashmap)/entry[@key=name()]" />*
      #<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>#
    </span>

  </xsl:for-each>
  [...]
```

Result :

```
<span class="panorama">* #PANO_LIV_MATIN#</span> - <span style="" class="panorama">* #PANO_LIV_MIN#</span>
```

Expected result :

```
<span class="panorama">Matin * #PANO_LIV_MATIN#</span> - <span style="" class="panorama">Ministre * #PANO_LIV_MIN#</span>
```

What works :

```
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($hashmap)/entry[@key='PANO_LIV_MATIN']" />
<!-- gives me Matin as expected -->
```

What not works but I don't know why :

```
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($hashmap)/entry[@key=name()]" />
<!-- gives me nothing, but the name() print exactly the good key if I put it in a xsl:value-of -->
```

What's wrong with the `name()` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with `name()` in your example is that it is at the wrong context node, because it is used in the select on your `$hashmap` you have to use a variable instead:

```
<xsl:for-each select="PANO_LIV_MATIN[text() = 'True'] | PANO_LIV_MIN[text() = 'True'] | PANO_LIV_INTER[text() = 'True']">
<xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>

<span class="panorama">
  <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($hashmap)/entry[@key=$name]" />*
  #<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>#
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($hashmap)/entry[@key = name(current())]" />`.

Comment: I was going to post that, but that is not allowed in XSLT 1.0

Comment: I tryed it, and didn't works... this maybe works only in XSLT > 1.0 :-)
But Thanks for your response :-)

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the sample to use XSLT 1.0 syntax with `name(current())`.